# Выход через proxy 127.0.0.1 в браузерах не работает

Tags: proxy, jmeter

Для тестирования использую jmeter и возникла необходимость записать действия в test script recorder этой программы. Запись производится путем указания порта, прокси-сервера и самого браузера (т.е. ходишь по страничкам и действия записываются). Я сделала все настройки как к мануале и в видео на ютубе, но возникает проблема, что ни один браузер не выходит в интернет через proxy 127.0.0.1 и разные номера портов типа 8080 или 8888. Подскажите, что можно сделать. В интернете советовалось почистить кэш, выключить все плагины, проверить есть ли в файле hosts адрес 127.0.0.1. Все проверила. Ничего не помогает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще снимала галочку у поля "Один прокси-сервер для всех протоколов" - тоже не помогло [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже скрин, что выводит браузер: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пинг до  адреса 127.0.0.1 прекрасно идет, без потери пакетов

Comment: А собственно прокси на указанных портах запущен ?

Comment: А как запустить на портах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы записать действия через test script recorder вам нужно **включить** этот самый test script recorder нажав кнопку Start

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предвосхищая следующий вопрос: для того чтобы записывать [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) траффик вам нужно будет добавить сертификат JMeter в ваш браузер как это описано в разделе **HTTPS recording and certificates** документации по [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

Файл называется `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` и он создается в джейметровской папке "bin" когда вы запускаете test script recorder.

Возможно вам будет проще и быстрее воспользоваться [расширением JMeter для Google Chrome](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium), в этом случае установки прокси и сертификатов не требуется.

Comment: Мне нужно не это. Записать я знаю как. Записывать нечего, если сайт не открывается. Сертификат установлен во все браузеры, порт я прописала в jmeter. Браузеры Мозила и Хром не открывают не один сайт по прокси 127.0.0.1 (или localhost если прописать) и номеру порта такому же как в jmeter.

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы сайты открывались в браузере. Потом я нажимаю на элементы на сайте и они записываются в jmeter. Но требование jmeter, чтобы подключение именно было по прокси 127.0.0.1 в браузере. Я настроила все по докуметации jmeter. Проблема с прокси у меня. Компьютер на виндоус 7, антивирус без файрволла Total360.

Comment: @Каролина Так вы нажимали на кнопку Start, как тут предлагают ? Программа должна быть сначала запущена, потому что именно она и есть прокси и только после этого есть смысл пытаться открывать сайты через этот прокси

Comment: Спасибо большое. Дошло, что сервер jmeter запускает.

Comment: Иногда вроде все сделаешь и где-то на глупом месте застреваешь. Еще раз спасибо. Я  сначала сайт открывала, а потом старт делала.